# When I create a template object to be used inside my Xamarin Forms code, is there a way I can use C# fluent with Build to create the template?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a template class that is in its own namespace and that I add to my code with `

```
new InfoLabel()`{ Text = "abc" };
```

Note that this is just a very simple example and I have other template objects that don't just depend on one thing, for example an object with 2-3 labels.

Is there a way that I can apply Xamarin C# fluent to create a templated object?

Here is the simple example object that I have:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class InfoLabel : Label
    {
        public InfoLabel()
        {
            SetDynamicResource(FontFamilyProperty, Const.Fonts.DefaultRegular);
            SetDynamicResource(FontSizeProperty, Const.Fonts.InfoTextFontSize);
            SetDynamicResource(TextColorProperty, Const.Colors.InfoLabelColor);
            LineBreakMode           = LineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            VerticalOptions         = LayoutOptions.Start;
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is how I can set up the same thing using the latest C# fluent standards?

Here is the way I think it might be done. I used a `Build()` method but I would appreciate if someone more skilled than me could tell me if I am doing it correctly as this is a big change from what I am used to:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class InfoLabel
    {
        public InfoLabel()
            {
                Build();
            }

        void Build() =>
            new Label
            {
                LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
            }
            .TextLeft()
            .DynamicResources((Label.FontFamilyProperty, Const.Fonts.DefaultRegular),
                              (Label.FontSizeProperty, Const.Fonts.InfoTextFontSize),
                              (Label.TextColorProperty, Const.Colors.InfoLabelColor));
```

Here is another idea that I have:

```
namespace Test
{

    public class InfoLabel : Label
    {
        public InfoLabel()
        {
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            Build();
        }

        void Build() =>
            this.TextLeft()
                .DynamicResources((Label.FontFamilyProperty, Const.Fonts.DefaultRegular),
                              (Label.FontSizeProperty, Const.Fonts.InfoTextFontSize),
                              (Label.TextColorProperty, Const.Colors.InfoLabelColor));
```

Note that I am using an extension method for the resources.

Comment: We can only set  `LineBreakMode` in the `{}` .Check https://github.com/VincentH-Net/CSharpForMarkup/blob/formsexample/CSharpMarkupIntro/CSharpMarkupIntro/SearchPage.cs

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I followed his example and did set that in the { }.  My biggest and most important question is can you tell me if the way I am doing it with putting Build in the constructor is a good way to go about doing it.   If you were to code up a template like I have done, how would you code it?   If different from my suggestion, can you give an example.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT - apologies, I changed slightly the text of the question as I realize you are correct with your advice but I am not sure about how to create the InfoLabel object.  Should I use Build() in the constructor?  Also if I do not inherit from Label then I will lose the ability to add things like Text =, so I am very confused how I can create this type of control / template object.  Note this is just an example in my app I have similar controls / templates that are more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the instance of label like following

```
 public class InfoLabel : Label
    {
        

        static InfoLabel CreateDefaultLabel()
        {
            return new InfoLabel
            {
                LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
            }
            .TextLeft()
            .DynamicResources((Label.FontFamilyProperty, Const.Fonts.DefaultRegular),
                              (Label.FontSizeProperty, Const.Fonts.InfoTextFontSize),
                              (Label.TextColorProperty, Const.Colors.InfoLabelColor));
        }

    }
```

```
var label = InfoLabel.CreateDefaultLabel();
```

For more details of the usage of markup you could check this **[blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/c-sharp-markup-for-xamarin-forms/)** .

Comment: This would be a problem if I then tried to set the text like this: InfoLabel.CreateDefaultLabel() { Text = "abc" }

Comment: Set it like `label.Text ="xxx"`